# string template substitution: each and every occurrence must be substituted

Tags: python, string, templates

I have the following MWE:

```
import string

class MyTemplate(string.Template):
   delimiter = '$'
   pattern = r'''
   \$(?:
   (?P<escaped>\$)|
   (?P<named>[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*)\$|
   (?P<braced>[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*)\$|
   (?P<invalid>)
   )
   '''
data1="max=$max$ min=$min$"
data2="max=$max$ "
print MyTemplate(data1).substitute({"max":"10","min":"1"})
print MyTemplate(data2).substitute({"max":"10","min":"1"})
print MyTemplate(data1).substitute({"max":"10"})
```

Of the 3 prints, I want that the only acceptable case is the first;
the last one raise an exception, but the second simply writes:

```
max=10
```

1. How can I detect this case (more values than placeholder)?
2. Is it possible to verify that a value is substituted only once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The real questions here are "what are you trying to achieve?" and "is it needed?" and "why is it needed?"

If you still need it after answering all this, then override `substitute` in your `MyTemplate` class. You'll be able to do any check you like. It might slow down your program, though.

On the other hand, `string.Template` (from python 2.6) are mostly used through `mystr.format()`. And then, replaced by f-strings (3.6) https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Comment: **"what are you trying to achieve?"**:
what i would like to achieve is to substitute placeholder from a str loaded from a file.
**"is it needed?"**: yes. **"why is it needed?"**: error checking. This answer does not answer the question. following this rationale, i do not need to use the Template function. on as second thought, i do not even need python.

Comment: Now that I know what you're trying to achieve, I could advise you to use Jinja. http://jinja.pocoo.org